# Swift Pass Data Between 2 ViewController List of String

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

i have 2 views:
-one for put name of player
-one for play to the game.
But i can't not pass the data of name in a list

When I compile I have this error:

> fatal error: Index out of range

```
//ViewController.swift

    if(segue.identifier == "segue"){
        let secondView = segue.destination as! PlayViewController

        var numberOfPlayer = 0

        if(n1.text?.isEmpty == false){
            secondView.Player[0] = n1.text!
            numberOfPlayer += 1
        }
        if(n2.text?.isEmpty == false){
            secondView.Player[1] = n2.text!
            numberOfPlayer += 1
        }
        if(n3.text?.isEmpty == false){
            secondView.Player[2] = n3.text!
            numberOfPlayer += 1
        }
        secondView.nbPlayer = numberOfPlayer
    }
}
```

_

```
//PlayViewController
class PlayViewController: UIViewController {

var Player = [String]()
var nbPlayer = Int()
```

Comment: What do you mean you cannot pass the data? Do you get a compile time or runtime error? Please explain specifically what is not working.

Comment: When i compile i have this error: Reading from private effective user settings.
fatal error: Index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PlayViewController.Player` is initialized as an empty array, hence the error when you are trying to access its elements by an index. You either have to initialize the array with default values for a certain length or you have to use append to insert elements to the array instead of assinging values by index.

Moreover, when accessing a `UITextField`s text property, you should use optional binding to unwrap the value, then check if the text is empty. There's also no need for the `numberOfPlayer` variable, you can just use the number of elements in `players` (please conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lower-camelCase for variable names and hence rename `Player` to `players`).

```
//ViewController.swift
if(segue.identifier == "segue"){
    let secondView = segue.destination as! PlayViewController

    if let text1 = n1.text, !text1.isEmpty {
        secondView.players.append(text1)
    }
    if let text2 = n2.text, !text2.isEmpty {
        secondView.players.append(text2)
    }
    if let text3 = n3.text, !text3.isEmpty {
        secondView.players.append(text3)
    }
    secondView.nbPlayer = secondView.players.count
}
```

It is probably an even better solution to initialize `nbPlayer` as a computed property, so it always reflects the number of elements in the `players` array. Or rather you shouldn't even store this number in a separate variable, just access `players.count` when it needs to be accessed.

```
//PlayViewController
class PlayViewController: UIViewController {
    var players = [String]()
    var nbPlayer:Int {
        return players.count
    }
    ...
}
```